# Use case of C++11 function declaration at block scope?

Tags: c++, c++11

It would seem I can declare a function at block scope:

```
int main()
{
    void f(); // OK
}
```

However I can't define it:

```
int main()
{
    void f() {}; // ERROR
}
```

My question is, of what use is a function declaration at block scope?  What is a use case?

Comment: Not all that much considering we have `auto f = []{...};`.

Comment: (It should be noted that this is completely unchanged from C++98/03, which works the same way. It isn't a new thing in C++11)

Comment: It's unchanged since K&R 'C' in about 1974 actually.

Comment: @chris: *lambdas* remove the need to *define* a function inline, but that was not the use of the *declaration*, moreover considering that you could not *define* the function inside the function block (and for class types, that could be defined, they could not be used in templates again reducing the use)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Yes, I'm sure I've seen it somewhere that you can declare it in block scope and define it outside, but that never came to mind until the answer was posted. I'll grant it that use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it. http://ideone.com/kJHGoF

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    void f(); // Forward declare function named "f" returning void in the
              // global namespace.
    f();
}

/*    
void g()
{
    f(); // ERROR!
}
*/

void f()
{
    std::puts("hello!");
}
```

I'm not sure why someone would actually want to use this. It is in the language this way for backwards compatibility with C; but I've got no idea what someone would do with this in C.

Comment: You can't define it *inside the method,* which is what the question is about.

Comment: @EJP: The definition does have code inside it. The OP says that the function declared at block scope cannot be defined, but that is false. The forward declaration isn't scoped to the block, it is a forward declaration for the global namespace.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't realize that the `f` name at block scope would "bind to" a later definition at global scope.  This is a little weird and obviously inconsistent with how block scope object declarations work.

Comment: Why is this "accepted?"  Question: "What is use case?" Alleged Answer: "I have no idea." <ACCEPTED>. SO is so broken at this point...

Answer (score 5):

It's sometimes a shortcut to declaring and calling an externally-linked function which itself isn't publically defined in a header.  For example, imagine you were linking against a C library which you knew provided a `LibDebugOn(int)` call but hadn't defined it in a header.  It can be a shortcut to declare and call it in one place:

```
void myFunc() {
  // call "Lib" but turn on debugging via hidden API
  extern "C" void LibDebugOn(int); // declare hidden C-linked function
  LibDebugOn(1);  // call it
  // do something with the library here...
  LibDebugOn(0);  // turn off lib debugging now
}
```

In fairness this is usually only worthwhile for a one-off quick hack, and not something to be encouraged.

Comment: What advantage does that have over declaring it outside of the function? It does not reduce the potential for name collisions, it would just move name collisions to link time rather than compile time.

Comment: Indeed, it's more a way of scoping the nasty hack to its usage, and so not actively promoting further use within the same source file. As you say, any actual collisions are found at link-time, but if you're linking against the C library you'll be running that risk anyway.

I suppose really it's pretty hard to come up with a convincing use case for this feature.  I imagine the feature is mostly a hangover from the unified way variables and functions are treated within a declarator.

Comment: This is actually a use case that I needed.  Why your answer is "unaccepted" and the "accepted" answer is "I've got no idea" is beyond the collective reasoning power of humankind.